# Alarm System In Location Based Services

Tags: android, alarm

I want to create Location Based Alarm System App.I am a beginner in Android developing field.So please give a procedure for doing this app(especially alarm setting procedure).

Answer (score 1):

This article explains Alarm Manager nicely.

```
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html
```

You have to use Google API for implementing the location based feature. I would suggest first going through the Alarm Manager tutorial and then following a tutorial on how to display simple location based toast messages. Once you have an idea of how both work, then you will be better equipped to handle this task. (Divide and Conquer)

Comment: Yes, i learned about Alarm Manager tutorial and Google API. Can you give procedure to combine these both..? please....

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a set of Geocoding APIs that can be used to reverse geocoding, but it's slightly more complicated to use, but it's much better than GeoCoder. For detailed usage of the Geocoding API, please refer to the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

The working principle of the Geocoding API is not mysterious. It is actually using the HTTP protocol we learned earlier. On the mobile side, we can initiate an HTTP request to Google's server, and pass the value of the latitude and longitude as a parameter. Then the server will help us convert this latitude and longitude value into a well-understood location information, and then return the information to the mobile phone. Finally, the mobile terminal will parse the information returned by the server and process it.

A number of interfaces are specified in the Geocoding API, where the reverse geocoding interface is as follows: